# How to use the word "range" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I am not sure about the correct usage of "range"

Should I say:

1) Usually a PCB dissipates power with a range of 5 watt to 30 watt.

2) Usually a PCB dissipates power ranges from 5 watt to 30 watt.

3) Usually a PCB dissipates power ranges between 5 watt to 30 watt.

cordially, let me know which sentence is correct and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example 1) could be used, but either "in" or "within" might fit better:

> Usually, a PCB dissipates power within a range of 5 to 30 watts.

It's not clear whether examples 2) and 3) are using "ranges" as a noun or a verb. If it's a noun, "power ranges" aren't what is dissipated, so the examples don't work. If "ranges" is intended as a verb, it doesn't fit into the sentence. However, you can use it as a verb, as in this example:

> Usually, PCB power dissipation ranges between 5 and 30 watts. or
>   Usually, PCB power dissipation ranges from 5 to 30 watts.

You could avoid "range" completely:

> Usually, a PCB dissipates between 5 and 30 watts of power. or
>   Usually, the power dissipation of a PCB lies between 5 and 30 watts.

Note that "watt" should be plural, and it doesn't need to be repeated.
(The only exceptions to the plural would be the exact value of "1 watt" or an expression like "less/greater than one watt".)

Comment: How about "... dissipates power ranging from 5 to 30 watts?"

Comment: @TypeIA That works nicely.